# Why is my linux partition not mounting?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, mount

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

I have the following partitions:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000LM024-2AN1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 34704922-427B-4EF0-86D0-C0652819C79B

Device         Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2       4096  251662335  251658240  120G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  251662336 7814033407 7562371072  3.5T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000LM024-2AN1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F440047A-FDC1-4BE6-BC90-6431947669EF

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 7814037134 7814035087  3.7T Linux filesystem
```

I would like to mount `snb1`to `/volume2`.
`/volume2` exists and all permissions are set correctly.
`bin  boot  cdrom  dev  etc  home  lib  lib32  lib64  libx32  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  p  path  proc  pvolume1  root  run  sbin  snap  srv  swap.img  sys  tmp  usr  var  volume1  volume2`

First I check the mounts:

```
lsblk -l
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0   7:0    0 61.8M  1 loop /snap/core20/1081
loop1   7:1    0 70.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21029
loop2   7:2    0 55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop3   7:3    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12704
loop4   7:4    0 20.3M  1 loop /snap/wormhole/349
loop5   7:5    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12883
sda     8:0    0  3.7T  0 disk 
sda1    8:1    0    1M  0 part 
sda2    8:2    0  120G  0 part /
sda3    8:3    0  3.5T  0 part /volume1
sdb     8:16   0  3.7T  0 disk 
sdb1    8:17   0  3.7T  0 part
```

`sdb1` is not mounted and nothing else is mounted in `/volume2`.
So I go ahead and mount sdb1 to /volume2
`sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /volume2`.
I get no error messages.

But when I check again:

```
lsblk -ls
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0   7:0    0 61.8M  1 loop /snap/core20/1081
loop1   7:1    0 70.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21029
loop2   7:2    0 55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop3   7:3    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12704
loop4   7:4    0 20.3M  1 loop /snap/wormhole/349
loop5   7:5    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12883
sda1    8:1    0    1M  0 part 
sda2    8:2    0  120G  0 part /
sda3    8:3    0  3.5T  0 part /volume1
sda     8:0    0  3.7T  0 disk 
sdb1    8:17   0  3.7T  0 part 
sdb     8:16   0  3.7T  0 disk
```

dmesg

```
[416.308245] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[ 2269.851670] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled
[ 2270.141007] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
```

[ 2270.195509] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O MODULE].
[ 2270.275631] QNX4 filesystem 0.2.3 registered.
[19482.126094] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[21069.712835] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

I get the same thing. sdb1 is just mot mounting.
I though I could resolve this with a reboot. But it does not want to work.
Why is that?

edit: I just tried:
`sudo mount -a /dev/sdb1 /volume2`. I now get:
`mount: /volume2: special device /dev/disk/by-uuid/dace6e49-5297-4a1a-8517-0e4fce045ce4 does not exist.`

[edit2]
output from `strace mount`:

```
sudo strace mount /dev/sdb1 /volume2
execve("/usr/bin/mount", ["mount", "/dev/sdb1", "/volume2"], 0x7ffdbc138da0 /* 13 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x559c8c554000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffef5382e70) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=29088, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 29088, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f92e57a1000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\313\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=387768, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f92e579f000
mmap(NULL, 390504, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f92e573f000
mmap(0x7f92e574a000, 253952, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xb000) = 0x7f92e574a000
mmap(0x7f92e5788000, 77824, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x49000) = 0x7f92e5788000
mmap(0x7f92e579b000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5b000) = 0x7f92e579b000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360q\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\t\233\222%\274\260\320\31\331\326\10\204\276X>\263"..., 68, 880) = 68
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2029224, ...}) = 0
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\t\233\222%\274\260\320\31\331\326\10\204\276X>\263"..., 68, 880) = 68
mmap(NULL, 2036952, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f92e554d000
mprotect(0x7f92e5572000, 1847296, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f92e5572000, 1540096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7f92e5572000
mmap(0x7f92e56ea000, 303104, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19d000) = 0x7f92e56ea000
mmap(0x7f92e5735000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7f92e5735000
mmap(0x7f92e573b000, 13528, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f92e573b000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\266\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=351352, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 354088, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f92e54f6000
mprotect(0x7f92e5500000, 290816, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f92e5500000, 221184, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xa000) = 0x7f92e5500000
mmap(0x7f92e5536000, 65536, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x40000) = 0x7f92e5536000
mmap(0x7f92e5547000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x50000) = 0x7f92e5547000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@p\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=163200, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 174600, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f92e54cb000
mprotect(0x7f92e54d1000, 135168, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f92e54d1000, 102400, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f92e54d1000
mmap(0x7f92e54ea000, 28672, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1f000) = 0x7f92e54ea000
mmap(0x7f92e54f2000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x26000) = 0x7f92e54f2000
mmap(0x7f92e54f4000, 6664, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f92e54f4000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=584392, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 586536, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f92e543b000
mmap(0x7f92e543d000, 409600, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f92e543d000
mmap(0x7f92e54a1000, 163840, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x66000) = 0x7f92e54a1000
mmap(0x7f92e54c9000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x8d000) = 0x7f92e54c9000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \22\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18816, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 20752, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f92e5435000
mmap(0x7f92e5436000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7f92e5436000
mmap(0x7f92e5438000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f92e5438000
mmap(0x7f92e5439000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f92e5439000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\201\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\345Ga\367\265T\320\374\301V)Yf]\223\337"..., 68, 824) = 68
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=157224, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f92e5433000
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\345Ga\367\265T\320\374\301V)Yf]\223\337"..., 68, 824) = 68
mmap(NULL, 140408, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f92e5410000
mmap(0x7f92e5417000, 69632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7000) = 0x7f92e5417000
mmap(0x7f92e5428000, 20480, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18000) = 0x7f92e5428000
mmap(0x7f92e542d000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c000) = 0x7f92e542d000
mmap(0x7f92e542f000, 13432, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f92e542f000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f92e540d000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f92e540d840) = 0
mprotect(0x7f92e5735000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f92e542d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f92e5439000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f92e54c9000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f92e54f2000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f92e5547000, 20480, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f92e579b000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x559c8c25f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f92e57d6000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f92e57a1000, 29088)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f92e540db10)         = 58500
set_robust_list(0x7f92e540db20, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7f92e5417bf0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f92e54253c0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7f92e5417c90, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f92e54253c0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0x7ffef5382dc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/selinux", 0x7ffef5382dc0)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
brk(NULL)                               = 0x559c8c554000
brk(0x559c8c575000)                     = 0x559c8c575000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\ttmpfs\nnodev\tbd"..., 1024) = 465
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/selinux/config", F_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3035952, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3035952, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f92e5127000
close(3)                                = 0
getuid()                                = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
access("/sys/fs/smackfs", F_OK)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/dev", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4260, ...}) = 0
lstat("/dev/sdb1", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x11), ...}) = 0
stat("/dev/sdb1", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x11), ...}) = 0
lstat("/volume2", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
access("/dev/sdb1", F_OK)               = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/sdb1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fadvise64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_RANDOM)   = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x11), ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, BLKGETSIZE64, [4000785964544]) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/8:17", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
openat(4, "dm/uuid", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/8:17", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
faccessat(4, "partition", F_OK)         = 0
readlink("/sys/dev/block/8:17", "../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00"..., 4095) = 83
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/block/sdb/dev", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
read(5, "8:16\n", 4096)                 = 5
close(5)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
lseek(3, 4000785891328, SEEK_SET)       = 4000785891328
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 64) = 64
lseek(3, 4000785952768, SEEK_SET)       = 4000785952768
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 256) = 256
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 256) = 256
lseek(3, 4096, SEEK_SET)                = 4096
read(3, "\323\5\0\0\343\5\0\0\363\5\0\0\7Z\365\37\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\27k\34\362\365\37\374\334"..., 256) = 256
lseek(3, 4000785964032, SEEK_SET)       = 4000785964032
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 4000785832960, SEEK_SET)       = 4000785832960
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 4096, SEEK_SET)                = 4096
read(3, "\323\5\0\0\343\5\0\0\363\5\0\0\7Z\365\37\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\27k\34\362\365\37\374\334"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 4000785960448, SEEK_SET)       = 4000785960448
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
lseek(3, 1024, SEEK_SET)                = 1024
read(3, "\0 \216\16\321\268:W4\351\2\306\313I9\365\37\216\16\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\2\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 16384, SEEK_SET)               = 16384
read(3, "\0\0`\0\20\0`\0 \0`\0\340_\0 \0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\371\23\0\0\0 \362\267"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 32768, SEEK_SET)               = 32768
read(3, "\0\0\340\0\20\0\340\0 \0\340\0\340_\0 \0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\371\23\0\0\0 \366\26"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 65536, SEEK_SET)               = 65536
read(3, "\0\0\340\1\20\0\340\1 \0\340\1\340_\0 \0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\371\23\0\0\0 \17\""..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 131072, SEEK_SET)              = 131072
read(3, "\0\0\340\3\20\0\340\3 \0\340\3\340_\0 \0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\371\23\0\0\0 \f="..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 262144, SEEK_SET)              = 262144
read(3, "\0\0\340\7\20\0\340\7 \0\340\7\340_\0 \0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\371\23\0\0\0 \n\3"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 524288, SEEK_SET)              = 524288
read(3, "\0\0\340\17\20\0\340\17 \0\340\17\340_\0 \0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\371\23\0\0\0 \6\177"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 1048576, SEEK_SET)             = 1048576
read(3, "\0\0\340\37\20\0\340\37 \0\340\37\340_\0 \0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\371\23\0\0\0 \36\207"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 2097152, SEEK_SET)             = 2097152
read(3, "\0\202\0\0\0\202\1\0\0\202\2\0\0\202\3\0\0\202\4\0\0\202\f\0\0\202\r\0\0\202\30\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 4194304, SEEK_SET)             = 4194304
read(3, "\0\204\0\0\0\204\1\0\0\204\2\0\0\204\3\0\0\204\4\0\0\204\f\0\0\204\r\0\0\204\30\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 1048576, SEEK_SET)             = 1048576
read(3, "\0\0\340\37\20\0\340\37 \0\340\37\340_\0 \0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\371\23\0\0\0 \36\207"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 3072, SEEK_SET)                = 3072
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 7168, SEEK_SET)                = 7168
read(3, "\0\0\30\0\20\0\30\0 \0\30\0\340_\0 \0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\371\23\0\0\0 \305\207"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 15360, SEEK_SET)               = 15360
read(3, "\0\0X\0\20\0X\0 \0X\0\340_\0 \0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\371\23\0\0\0 GW"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 31744, SEEK_SET)               = 31744
read(3, "\0\0\330\0\20\0\330\0 \0\330\0\340_\0 \0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\371\23\0\0\0 C\366"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 64512, SEEK_SET)               = 64512
read(3, "\0\0\330\1\20\0\330\1 \0\330\1\340_\0 \0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\371\23\0\0\0 \272\302"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f92e50e6000
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 262144) = 262144
lseek(3, 262144, SEEK_SET)              = 262144
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f92e50a5000
read(3, "\0\0\340\7\20\0\340\7 \0\340\7\340_\0 \0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\371\23\0\0\0 \n\3"..., 262144) = 262144
lseek(3, 4000785367040, SEEK_SET)       = 4000785367040
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f92e5064000
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 262144) = 262144
lseek(3, 4000785629184, SEEK_SET)       = 4000785629184
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f92e5023000
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 262144) = 262144
lseek(3, 2097152, SEEK_SET)             = 2097152
read(3, "\0\202\0\0\0\202\1\0\0\202\2\0\0\202\3\0\0\202\4\0\0\202\f\0\0\202\r\0\0\202\30\0"..., 1024) = 1024
ioctl(3, BLKSSZGET, [512])              = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/8:16", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
readlink("/sys/dev/block/8:16", "../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00"..., 4095) = 78
stat("/dev/sdb", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x10), ...}) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/sdb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fadvise64(4, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_RANDOM)   = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x10), ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, BLKGETSIZE64, [4000787030016]) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/8:16", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
openat(5, "dm/uuid", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(5)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/8:16", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
faccessat(5, "partition", F_OK)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(5, "dm/uuid", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(5)                                = 0
ioctl(4, CDROM_GET_CAPABILITY, 0)       = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(4, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
ioctl(4, BLKSSZGET, [512])              = 0
lseek(4, 1024, SEEK_SET)                = 1024
read(4, "\257=\306\17\203\204rG\216y=i\330G}\344b\237\216\tO\225N\347\240.\204\326\16\353r\377"..., 16384) = 16384
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/8:17", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
openat(5, "size", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)   = 6
fcntl(6, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
read(6, "7814035087\n", 4096)           = 11
close(6)                                = 0
openat(5, "start", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 6
fcntl(6, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
read(6, "2048\n", 4096)                 = 5
close(6)                                = 0
close(5)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f92e50e6000, 266240)          = 0
munmap(0x7f92e50a5000, 266240)          = 0
munmap(0x7f92e5064000, 266240)          = 0
munmap(0x7f92e5023000, 266240)          = 0
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/sbin/mount.ext4", 0x7ffef5380af0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sbin/fs.d/mount.ext4", 0x7ffef5380af0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sbin/fs/mount.ext4", 0x7ffef5380af0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getuid()                                = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getgid()                                = 0
getegid()                               = 0
prctl(PR_GET_DUMPABLE)                  = 1 (SUID_DUMP_USER)
stat("/run", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=1060, ...}) = 0
lstat("/run/mount/utab", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=377, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/mount/utab", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=377, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
access("/run/mount/utab", R_OK|W_OK)    = 0
mount("/dev/sdb1", "/volume2", "ext4", 0, NULL) = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: that results in nothing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is mount failing silently for me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459950/why-is-mount-failing-silently-for-me)

Comment: I tried the `strace mount`. There is a very long output. Probably too long to add it to the question. And I am afraid I cant decipher the output.
But I had an output on `mount -a`. I added it to the question

Comment: what's that uuid, from fstab? is it valid? check blkid

Comment: ok. though my question was valid without the prehistory. Basically I had sdb1 mounted on /volume2 before. But then fiddled with partitioning sdb and had to resetup the disk. It has a new UID now and fstab has the old UID in it. I updated fastab now and will have to reboot. can't do this from here (remote) though as there also is a problem with autodetect in UEFI. Have to be there locally to select the boot drive. It's all a bit messed up. I am currently trying to save my data to sdb so I can re-setup the entire system. I think our hint with fstab was the answer.

Comment: put it in as an answer and i'll mark it solved

Comment: I don't think it is the answer as we can see from dmesg sdb1 mounted successfully, it's still unclear what is unmounting right after. Not sure if related to invalid fstab entry at all

Comment: I added the `strace mount` output to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the situation was, that when selecting the USB drive in UEFI menu to install linux, it presented me with the BIOS install first. The UEFI install was the next down in the dropdown menu. I didn't check for that and installed Ubuntu server in BIOS mode.
Not knowing that error, I made all boot partitions UEFI. These were then not recognised as valid boot partitions in my particular installation. So I had to manually choose the correct hard drive in UEFI every time I rebooted.
I did a complete reinstall to fix it.

Comment: Too late now, but it's actually not too difficult to fix this, especially if you already are using GPT and have room for a efi partition.